# How to generate certificate from user data on firebase database

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an online course selling app, and there I need to develop an automatic certificate generator with student names and course names. How can I integrate that?
and I saw some websites for certificate generating, can I integrate that in Flutter app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [syncfusion_flutter_pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf) package for generate certificate as pdf. You can check out this [example](https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/pdf/course-completion-certificate). Maybe this is exactly what you want.
you can also find code related to this example [here](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/blob/master/lib/samples/pdf/certificate.dart).
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you want to design the certificate yourself. There are a couple of ways you can do that like creating it using widgets or using an image. If you use an image, you'll have to layer the user's info on top, which can be tricky to position correctly. Personally, I would probably generate the certificate using widgets and a package like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) to create the image from that.